# My SQL query to refresh the value of a column after passing a week

Tags: mysql

> |User_ID |Weekly_Score|Total_Score|

this is my table and User_ID is primary key. How should I write a query to refresh the value in Weekly_score to 0 with the start of new week? (Last week score is 20 and total score is 50.With start of new week it should be 0 and 50. )

Comment: Have you read this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html ?

Comment: You should use events for this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MySql event with an `UPDATE` statement

```sql
CREATE EVENT ev_reset_weekly_scores
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2013-01-30 00:00:00' DO
  UPDATE scores
     SET Total_Score = Total_Score + Weekly_Score, 
         Weekly_Score = 0;
```

**Note:** make sure that you specify correct start datetime for your event.

Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to check if event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "Daemon" by user "event_scheduler". Use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled. More on configuring event scheduler here.

Alternatively you can run your update statement with `mysql` CLI using cron or Windows Task Scheduler (if you are on Windows).